# Pair matching elements from two lists

Tags: scala, recursion

Here is a method that takes two lists (`l1` and `l2`) and pairs up elements that "match". As you can see at the end of the code block these lists consist of matching elements but in different indexes. The method `pairUp` outputs matching elements paired up, and discards those without a pair.

I spent way too much time writing this method, and it feels clumsy and complex, not scala idiomatic.

How could I have done this simpler? and could I make it faster?

```
case class A(serial:Int) {
  def matches(b:B):Boolean = this.serial == b.serial
}
case class B(serial:Int)

import scala.annotation.tailrec
@tailrec def pairUp(
  list1:List[A],
  list2:List[B],
  i:Int=0,
  pairs:List[(A, B)]=List.empty[(A,B)]
):List[(A,B)] = {
  if (list1.isEmpty || list2.isEmpty) return pairs
  else {
    if (i == list2.length)  // this list1 element has no match
      return pairUp(
        list1.tail,         // so discard
        list2,
        0, // reset counter
        pairs)      
    else {
      if (list1.head matches list2.head) // these elements match
        return pairUp(
          list1.tail,
          list2.tail,
          0,
          pairs :+ ((list1.head, list2.head)))
      else
        return pairUp(
          list1,
          list2.tail :+ list2.head, // list2 element to back
          i + 1,
          pairs)
    }
  }
}

val l1 = List(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5).map(A(_))
val l2 = List(1, 3, 0, 2, 4).map(B(_))

val pairs = pairUp(l1, l2)
// List((A(0),B(0)), (A(1),B(1)), (A(2),B(2)), (A(3),B(3)), (A(4),B(4)))
println(pairs)
```

Comment: Simpler or faster, pick one. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am not an expert at scala, but this works for me

```
def pairUp2( list1: List[A], list2: List[B]): List[(A, B)] = {
    (for{
     a <- list1
     b <- list2
     if a.serial == b.serial
   } yield (a,b))
 }

 val pairs = pairUp2(l1, l2)
 pairs: List[(A, B)] = List((A(0),B(0)), (A(1),B(1)), (A(2),B(2)), (A(3),B(3)), (A(4),B(4)))
```

The for comprehension, takes each element of list1 and an element of list2 and yields a tuple only if the serial values match.

Comment: Simplicity of this is refreshing. However, I'm trying to wrap my head around how to tell which method provides more speed and/or lower footprint.

Comment: @DominykasMostauskis This solution is O(nm), where n and m are the respective sizes of list1 and list2.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that is fairly compact and fast for large lists, but returns the two disordered:

```
def pairUp(list1: List[A], list2: List[B]): List[(A, B)] = {
  val g1 = list1.groupBy(_.serial).toList
  val g2 = list2.groupBy(_.serial)
  g1.flatMap{ case (k,as) => g2.get(k).toList.flatMap(as zip _) }
}
```

If you want to keep them ordered, then it's a bit more bookkeeping:

```
def pairUp2(list1: List[A], list2: List[B]): List[(A, B)] = {
  val g1 = list1.zipWithIndex.groupBy(_._1.serial).toList
  val g2 = list2.groupBy(_.serial)
  val temp = g1.flatMap{ case (k,as) => 
    g2.get(k).toList.flatMap(as zip _)
  }
  temp.sortBy(_._1._2).map{ case ((a,_), b) => (a,b) }
}
```

Note that the direct `O(n^2)` search will be faster if `n` is small.

Answer (score 2):

A version that's probably no faster but slightly less verbose. I'm sure there's a much better way but it's a start:

```
case class A(serial: Int) {
  def matches(b: B): Boolean = this.serial == b.serial
}
case class B(serial: Int)

def pairUp2(list1: List[A], list2: List[B]): List[(A,B)] = {
  def pairInc(l1: List[A], l2: List[B], pairs: List[(A,B)]): List[(A,B)] = l1 match {
    case a :: rest => l2.indexWhere(b => a.matches(b)) match {
      case -1 => pairInc(rest, l2, pairs)
      case i => pairInc(rest, l2.patch(i, List.empty[B], 1), pairs :+ (a, l2(i)))
    }
    case Nil => pairs
  }
  pairInc(list1, list2, List.empty)
}

val l1 = List(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5).map(A)
val l2 = List(1, 3, 0, 2, 4).map(B)

val pairs = pairUp2(l1, l2, matchFn)
// List((A(0),B(0)), (A(1),B(1)), (A(2),B(2)), (A(3),B(3)), (A(4),B(4)))
println(pairs)
```

This assumes that duplicate values in one list but not the other will only pair once. Otherwise you could use foldLeft, like so:

```
def pairUp3(list1: List[A], list2: List[B]): List[(A,B)] = {
  list1.foldLeft(List.empty[(A,B)]) { case (p, a) =>
    list2.find(b => a.matches(b)) match {
      case Some(b) => p :+ (a, b)
      case None => p
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you first sort the lists, matching only takes a single traversal, making the solution O(n log(n)) (which is the time complexity of the sorts).  I've also generalized over the lists' element types, only requiring projection functions `proj*` that can convert `A` and `B` into some common type `C` that can then be ordered (for sorting) and compared with `==`.

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

def zipMatching[A, B, C](a: List[A], b: List[B], projA: A => C, projB: B => C)
                        (implicit ord: Ordering[C]): List[(A, B)] = {
  import ord._ // Get access to `>`

  @tailrec
  def zipSortedMatching(
    aSorted: List[A], bSorted: List[B], accum: List[(A, B)]
  ): List[(A, B)] = {
    (aSorted, bSorted) match {
      case (aHead +: aRest, bHead +: bRest) =>
        val compA = projA(aHead)
        val compB = projB(bHead)

        if (compA == compB)
          zipSortedMatching(aRest, bRest, accum :+ (aHead, bHead))
        else if (compA > compB)
          zipSortedMatching(aSorted, bRest, accum)
        else
          zipSortedMatching(aRest, bSorted, accum)
      case _ =>
        accum
    }
  }

  zipSortedMatching(a.sortBy(projA), b.sortBy(projB), Nil)
}


case class AA(serial: Int)
case class BB(serial: Int)

val l1 = List(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5).map(AA(_))
val l2 = List(1, 3, 0, 2, 4).map(BB(_))

def projAA(a: AA) = a.serial
def projBB(b: BB) = b.serial

val pairs = zipMatching(l1, l2, projAA, projBB)
// pairs: List[(AA, BB)] = List((AA(0),BB(0)), (AA(1),BB(1)), (AA(2),BB(2)), (AA(3),BB(3)), (AA(4),BB(4)))
```

Answer (score 0):

A small comment: it's awkward that `matches` is a member function of `A` and not `B`.  It would be cleaner to have `matches` as an individual function.

Comment: This may be a valuable comment, but it should be posted as one. I.e. this doesn't qualify as an answer.

Comment: @Dominykas A code review is basically just a list of comments.  My list has only one item.

Comment: Fair enough, I retract my critique. However, SE doesn't let me retract my downvote, unless the answer is edited.